# Getting problem when trying to integrate Button component with react storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, vite, storybook

Below is my ocmplete setup of Storybook sith react/typescript with VITE. Now my UI when i start the story book is giving me an error when i try to work with Button story: the error says: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module:

```
http://localhost:6006/src/components/UI/Button/Button.stories.tsx?t=1690970551524
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:6006/src/components/UI/Button/Button.stories.tsx?t=1690970551524
```

// src/components/UI/Button/Button.stories.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react';
import Button, { ButtonProps } from './Button';

// The "Meta" object describes the stories and provides additional information
export default {
  title: 'Components/UI/Button', // Updated title path to match the main.ts configuration
  component: Button,
} as Meta;

// Create a default story for the Button
const Template: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

// Default story with text inside the button
const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  children: 'Click me',
};

export { Default as ButtonDefault };




// .storybook/preview.ts

import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;







.storybook/preview.ts

import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/types';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/components/UI/Stories/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
};

export default config;








// .storybook/main.ts (or .storybook/main.js)

const config = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.mdx',
    '../src/components/UI/Button/Button.stories.tsx', // Corrected path for Button stories
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
};

export default config;
```

// src/components/UI/Button/Button.tsx

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { useConfig } from '../ConfigProvider'
import { useForm } from '../Form/context'
import { useInputGroup } from '../InputGroup/context'
import useColorLevel from '../hooks/useColorLevel'
import { CONTROL_SIZES, SIZES } from '../utils/constants'
import { Spinner } from '../Spinner'
import type { CommonProps, TypeAttributes, ColorLevel } from '../@types/common'
import type { ReactNode, ComponentPropsWithRef, MouseEvent } from 'react'

export interface ButtonProps
    extends CommonProps,
        Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>, 'onClick'> {
    active?: boolean
    block?: boolean
    color?: string
    disabled?: boolean
    icon?: string | ReactNode
    loading?: boolean
    onClick?: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
    shape?: TypeAttributes.Shape
    size?: TypeAttributes.Size
    variant?: 'solid' | 'twoTone' | 'plain' | 'default'
}

type ButtonColor = {
    bgColor: string
    hoverColor: string
    activeColor: string
    textColor: string
}

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>((props, ref) => {
    const {
        active = false,
        block = false,
        children,
        className,
        color = '',
        disabled,
        icon,
        loading = false,
        shape = 'round',
        size,
        variant = 'default',
        ...rest
    } = props
    const { themeColor, controlSize, primaryColorLevel } = useConfig()
    const formControlSize = useForm()?.size
    const inputGroupSize = useInputGroup()?.size
    const defaultClass = 'button'
    const sizeIconClass = 'inline-flex items-center justify-center'

    const splitedColor = color?.split('-') || []

    const buttonSize = size || inputGroupSize || formControlSize || controlSize
    const buttonColor = splitedColor[0] || themeColor
    const buttonColorLevel = splitedColor[1] || primaryColorLevel

    const [increaseLevel, decreaseLevel] = useColorLevel(
        buttonColorLevel as ColorLevel
    )

    const getButtonSize = () => {
        let sizeClass = ''
        switch (buttonSize) {
            case SIZES.LG:
                sizeClass = classNames(
                    `h-${CONTROL_SIZES.lg}`,
                    icon && !children
                        ? `w-${CONTROL_SIZES.lg} ${sizeIconClass} text-2xl`
                        : 'px-8 py-2 text-base'
                )
                break
            case SIZES.SM:
                sizeClass = classNames(
                    `h-${CONTROL_SIZES.sm}`,
                    icon && !children
                        ? `w-${CONTROL_SIZES.sm} ${sizeIconClass} text-lg`
                        : 'px-3 py-2 text-sm'
                )
                break
            case SIZES.XS:
                sizeClass = classNames(
                    `h-${CONTROL_SIZES.xs}`,
                    icon && !children
                        ? `w-${CONTROL_SIZES.xs} ${sizeIconClass} text-base`
                        : 'px-3 py-1 text-xs'
                )
                break
            default:
                sizeClass = classNames(
                    `h-${CONTROL_SIZES.md}`,
                    icon && !children
                        ? `w-${CONTROL_SIZES.md} ${sizeIconClass} text-xl`
                        : 'px-8 py-2'
                )
                break
        }
        return sizeClass
    }

    const disabledClass = 'opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed'

    const solidColor = () => {
        const btn = {
            bgColor: active
                ? `bg-${buttonColor}-${increaseLevel}`
                : `bg-${buttonColor}-${buttonColorLevel}`,
            textColor: 'text-white',
            hoverColor: active
                ? ''
                : `hover:bg-${buttonColor}-${decreaseLevel}`,
            activeColor: `active:bg-${buttonColor}-${increaseLevel}`,
        }
        return getBtnColor(btn)
    }

    const twoToneColor = () => {
        const btn = {
            bgColor: active
                ? `bg-${buttonColor}-200 dark:bg-${buttonColor}-50`
                : `bg-${buttonColor}-50 dark:bg-${buttonColor}-500 dark:bg-opacity-20`,
            textColor: `text-${buttonColor}-${buttonColorLevel} dark:text-${buttonColor}-50`,
            hoverColor: active
                ? ''
                : `hover:bg-${buttonColor}-100 dark:hover:bg-${buttonColor}-500 dark:hover:bg-opacity-30`,
            activeColor: `active:bg-${buttonColor}-200 dark:active:bg-${buttonColor}-500 dark:active:bg-opacity-40`,
        }
        return getBtnColor(btn)
    }

    const defaultColor = () => {
        const btn = {
            bgColor: active
                ? `bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-500 dark:border-gray-500`
                : `bg-white border border-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-700`,
            textColor: `text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100`,
            hoverColor: active ? '' : `hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600`,
            activeColor: `active:bg-gray-100 dark:active:bg-gray-500 dark:active:border-gray-500`,
        }
        return getBtnColor(btn)
    }

    const plainColor = () => {
        const btn = {
            bgColor: active
                ? `bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-500`
                : 'bg-transparent border border-transparent',
            textColor: `text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100`,
            hoverColor: active ? '' : `hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600`,
            activeColor: `active:bg-gray-100 dark:active:bg-gray-500 dark:active:border-gray-500`,
        }
        return getBtnColor(btn)
    }

    const getBtnColor = ({
        bgColor,
        hoverColor,
        activeColor,
        textColor,
    }: ButtonColor) => {
        return `${bgColor} ${
            disabled || loading ? disabledClass : hoverColor + ' ' + activeColor
        } ${textColor}`
    }

    const btnColor = () => {
        switch (variant) {
            case 'solid':
                return solidColor()
            case 'twoTone':
                return twoToneColor()
            case 'plain':
                return plainColor()
            case 'default':
                return defaultColor()
            default:
                return defaultColor()
        }
    }

    const classes = classNames(
        defaultClass,
        btnColor(),
        `radius-${shape}`,
        getButtonSize(),
        className,
        block ? 'w-full' : ''
    )

    const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        const { onClick } = props
        if (disabled || loading) {
            e.preventDefault()
            return
        }
        onClick?.(e)
    }

    const renderChildren = () => {
        if (loading && children) {
            return (
                <span className="flex items-center justify-center">
                    <Spinner enableTheme={false} className="mr-1" />
                    {children}
                </span>
            )
        }

        if (icon && !children && loading) {
            return <Spinner enableTheme={false} />
        }

        if (icon && !children && !loading) {
            return <>{icon}</>
        }

        if (icon && children && !loading) {
            return (
                <span className="flex items-center justify-center">
                    <span className="text-lg">{icon}</span>
                    <span className="ltr:ml-1 rtl:mr-1">{children}</span>
                </span>
            )
        }

        return <>{children}</>
    }

    return (
        <button ref={ref} className={classes} {...rest} onClick={handleClick}>
            {renderChildren()}
        </button>
    )
})

Button.displayName = 'Button'

export default Button
```